# Cordova Change Page | cannot redefine property: org ripple.js:38

Tags: cordova, ripple

When I change the page, I got this error on developer tools.
Error: cannot redefine property: org ripple.js:38 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova applications should adopt the SPA (Single Page Application) design. I think multi page uses is not appropriate for Cordova Application. 
We should adhere to the Single Page Application principle.